# Oculus Rift with Antichamber on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: games, steam, programming

Antichamber runs great on linux (steam version). But it is not playable with the Oculus Rift at this point.

The issues are: 1) no headtracking 2) graphics are not being split and distorted by Oculus SDK

My current plan is to use LD_PRELOAD to add the functionality, this seems to be the linux equivalent of DLL injection. Antichamber appears to be using SDL, I'm hoping this can be configured to use the headtracking data as a joystick and apply the graphics distortion, but I am not sure which functions I should be looking for.

Is there a simpler way of getting these issues resolved? Is SDL the right choice here?

Would appreciate any information on how the Unreal Engine 3 works under linux; and library injection too.

EDIT:

Here is the information I have so far, still not sure which functions I should be looking for (not familiar with SDL or OpenGL):

Articles on LD_PRELOAD and shared object injection; [here](http://rafalcieslak.wordpress.com/2013/04/02/dynamic-linker-tricks-using-ld_preload-to-cheat-inject-features-and-investigate-programs/) and [here](http://brundlelab.wordpress.com/2009/09/25/dll-injection-baby/)

Antichamber (steam version) directory is: ~/.steam/steam/SteamApps/common/Antichamber

The executable is at: Antichamber/Binaries/Linux/UDKGame-Linux

Had to install libvorbisfile3:i386 to get the executable to run from the command line. (Steam was able to start the game without installing this)

```
$ldd UDKGame-Linux
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf775d000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xf7716000)
    libSDL2_mixer-2.0.so.0 => /home/workstation/.steam/steam/SteamApps/common/Antichamber/Binaries/Linux/./lib/libSDL2_mixer-2.0.so.0 (0xf76d0000)
    libogg.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libogg.so.0 (0xf76c6000)
    libvorbis.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvorbis.so.0 (0xf769a000)
    libvorbisfile.so.3 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvorbisfile.so.3 (0xf7690000)
    libSDL2-2.0.so.0 => /home/workstation/.steam/steam/SteamApps/common/Antichamber/Binaries/Linux/./lib/libSDL2-2.0.so.0 (0xf75a7000)
    libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib32/nvidia-331-updates/libGL.so.1 (0xf74a3000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xf749d000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0xf7494000)
    libsteam_api.so => /home/workstation/.steam/steam/SteamApps/common/Antichamber/Binaries/Linux/./lib/libsteam_api.so (0xf7481000)
    libtcmalloc.so.0 => /home/workstation/.steam/steam/SteamApps/common/Antichamber/Binaries/Linux/./lib/libtcmalloc.so.0 (0xf7424000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf733b000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xf72f4000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf72d7000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf7127000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf775e000)
    libnvidia-tls.so.331.38 => /usr/lib32/nvidia-331-updates/tls/libnvidia-tls.so.331.38 (0xf7123000)
    libnvidia-glcore.so.331.38 => /usr/lib32/nvidia-331-updates/libnvidia-glcore.so.331.38 (0xf4edf000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0xf4daa000)
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0xf4d97000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0xf4d75000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0xf4d71000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0xf4d6a000)
$ nm -Du UDKGame-Linux
         U abort
         U accept
         U access
         U __assert_fail
         U backtrace
         U bind
         U chdir
         U close
         U closedir
         U connect
         U __ctype_b_loc
         U __ctype_toupper_loc
         U __cxa_atexit
         U __cxa_begin_catch
         U __cxa_call_unexpected
         U __cxa_end_catch
         U __cxa_guard_abort
         U __cxa_guard_acquire
         U __cxa_guard_release
         U __cxa_pure_virtual
         U difftime
         U __divdi3
         U dlclose
         U dlerror
         U dlopen
         U dlsym
         U __errno_location
         U fclose
         U fcntl
         U feof
         U ferror
         U fflush
         U fgets
         U __finitef
         U fopen
         U fprintf
         U fputc
         U fread
         U free
         U frexp
         U fseek
         U ftell
         U fwrite
         U __fxstat
         U getcwd
         U getenv
         U gethostname
         U getifaddrs
         U getpid
         U getsockname
         U getsockopt
         U gettimeofday
         U glAlphaFunc
         U glBegin
         U glBindTexture
         U glBlendFunc
         U glClear
         U glClearColor
         U glClearDepth
         U glClearStencil
         U glColorMask
         U glCullFace
         U glDeleteTextures
         U glDepthFunc
         U glDepthMask
         U glDepthRange
         U glDisable
         U glDrawArrays
         U glDrawBuffer
         U glEnable
         U glEnd
         U glGenTextures
         U glGetIntegerv
         U glGetString
         U glPixelStorei
         U glPolygonMode
         U glPolygonOffset
         U glReadBuffer
         U glReadPixels
         U glScissor
         U glStencilFunc
         U glStencilMask
         U glStencilOp
         U glTexCoord2f
         U glTexEnvf
         U glTexImage2D
         U glTexParameteri
         U glTexSubImage2D
         U glVertex2f
         U glViewport
         U glXGetClientString
         U glXGetProcAddressARB
         U glXQueryVersion
         w __gmon_start__
         U gmtime
         U gmtime_r
         U __gxx_personality_v0
         U inet_addr
         U ioctl
         U isalnum
         U isalpha
         U __isinff
         U __isnanf
         U isspace
         U iswpunct
         w _Jv_RegisterClasses
         U __libc_start_main
         U listen
         U localtime_r
         U lseek
         U malloc
         U memcmp
         U memcpy
         U memmove
         U memset
         U MinorityMix_SetPosition
         U mkdir
         U __moddi3
         U open
         U opendir
         U ov_clear
         U ov_info
         U ov_open_callbacks
         U ov_pcm_seek_page
         U ov_pcm_total
         U ov_read
         U ov_time_total
         U pause
         U powf
         U printf
         U pthread_cond_broadcast
         U pthread_cond_destroy
         U pthread_cond_init
         U pthread_cond_signal
         U pthread_cond_timedwait
         U pthread_cond_wait
         U pthread_create
         U pthread_detach
         U pthread_getspecific
         U pthread_key_create
         U pthread_key_delete
         U pthread_mutexattr_init
         U pthread_mutexattr_settype
         U pthread_mutex_destroy
         U pthread_mutex_init
         U pthread_mutex_lock
         U pthread_mutex_unlock
         U pthread_self
         U pthread_setspecific
         U qsort
         U rand
         U read
         U readdir
         U realloc
         U recv
         U recvfrom
         U rename
         U rmdir
         U sched_yield
         U SDL_BuildAudioCVT
         U SDL_ClearError
         U SDL_CloseAudio
         U SDL_ConvertAudio
         U SDL_ConvertSurfaceFormat
         U SDL_CreateRGBSurface
         U SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface
         U SDL_CreateWindow
         U SDL_DestroyWindow
         U SDL_Error
         U SDL_FillRect
         U SDL_free
         U SDL_FreeSurface
         U SDL_GameControllerClose
         U SDL_GameControllerOpen
         U SDL_GetClosestDisplayMode
         U SDL_GetDesktopDisplayMode
         U SDL_GetDisplayMode
         U SDL_GetError
         U SDL_GetKeyboardFocus
         U SDL_GetNumDisplayModes
         U SDL_GetNumVideoDisplays
         U SDL_GetPrefPath
         U SDL_GetWindowDisplayIndex
         U SDL_GetWindowSize
         U SDL_GL_CreateContext
         U SDL_GL_DeleteContext
         U SDL_GL_MakeCurrent
         U SDL_GL_SetAttribute
         U SDL_GL_SwapWindow
         U SDL_Init
         U SDL_IsGameController
         U SDL_isspace
         U SDL_LockAudioDevice
         U SDL_malloc
         U SDL_memcmp
         U SDL_memcpy
         U SDL_memset
         U SDL_MixAudioFormat
         U SDL_NumJoysticks
         U SDL_OpenAudioDevice
         U SDL_PauseAudioDevice
         U SDL_PollEvent
         U SDL_PushEvent
         U SDL_Quit
         U SDL_ReadBE32
         U SDL_ReadLE16
         U SDL_ReadLE32
         U SDL_realloc
         U SDL_RWFromFile
         U SDL_SetColorKey
         U SDL_SetError
         U SDL_SetHint
         U SDL_SetMainReady
         U SDL_SetWindowGrab
         U SDL_SetWindowIcon
         U SDL_ShowCursor
         U SDL_snprintf
         U SDL_sscanf
         U SDL_strcmp
         U SDL_strncasecmp
         U SDL_strncmp
         U SDL_UnlockAudioDevice
         U SDL_UpperBlit
         U SDL_WarpMouseInWindow
         U select
         U send
         U sendto
         U setsockopt
         U snprintf
         U socket
         U sprintf
         U srand
         U sscanf
         U SteamAPI_Init
         U SteamAPI_RegisterCallback
         U SteamAPI_RegisterCallResult
         U SteamAPI_RestartAppIfNecessary
         U SteamAPI_RunCallbacks
         U SteamAPI_Shutdown
         U SteamAPI_UnregisterCallback
         U SteamAPI_UnregisterCallResult
         U SteamApps
         U SteamFriends
         U SteamGameServer
         U SteamGameServer_BSecure
         U SteamGameServer_GetSteamID
         U SteamGameServer_Init
         U SteamGameServerNetworking
         U SteamGameServer_RunCallbacks
         U SteamGameServer_Shutdown
         U SteamGameServerStats
         U SteamGameServerUtils
         U SteamMatchmaking
         U SteamMatchmakingServers
         U SteamNetworking
         U SteamRemoteStorage
         U SteamUser
         U SteamUserStats
         U SteamUtils
         U stpcpy
         U strcasecmp
         U strchr
         U strcmp
         U strcpy
         U strdup
         U strlen
         U strncat
         U strncmp
         U strncpy
         U strrchr
         U strstr
         U strtod
         U strtol
         U swscanf
         U time
         U tolower
         U toupper
         U towupper
         U __umoddi3
         U unlink
         U _Unwind_Resume
         U usleep
         U utimes
         U vsnprintf
         U vsprintf
         U vswprintf
         U wcscat
         U wcschr
         U wcscmp
         U wcscpy
         U wcslen
         U wcsncmp
         U wcsncpy
         U wcsrchr
         U wcsstr
         U wcstod
         U wcstoul
         U wcstoull
         U wprintf
         U write
         U __xstat
         U _ZSt9terminatev
```